# Content area setting not working in UIScrollView in NIB settings

Tags: objective-c

I have setup the the content area for `UIScrollView` in NIB file but i can see it no more scrollable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add some view programmatically, you must add in your code (programmatically), a good place to add a UIButton is in the viewDidLoad methods in your implementation (.m) file, here an example:

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// other code...

UIButton *newButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 40, 40)];
[newButton setTitle:@"ProButton" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
// more properties you can configurate. See Apple doc
[newButton addTarget:self action:@selector(methodToFire:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
// more action you can configurate for event...
[self.view addSubview:newButton];

// more code...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to this code:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(buttonClickMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Button Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(50.0, 100.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[view addSubview:button];
```